# Material-UI typography error in React + Jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui, typography

I am not seeing any warning from my React web app when I run the application in the browser, but during my unit test run I am getting Material-UI typography error.

> Warning: Material-UI: you are using the deprecated typography variants that will be removed in the next major release.
>         Please read the migration guide under https://material-ui.com/style/typography#migration-to-typography-v2

Please suggest how to resolve the issue.

The migration guide didn't help in this regard because I have upgraded all the Typography variants to latest as mentioned in the document.

**@material-ui/core Version : 3.5.1**

> yarn run v1.9.4 $ node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom
>
> PASS  src/containers/Login/Login.spec.js   ● Console
>
> ```
> console.error node_modules/warning/warning.js:34
>   Warning: Material-UI: you are using the deprecated typography variants that will be removed in the next major release.
>   Please read the migration guide under https://material-ui.com/style/typography#migration-to-typography-v2
> ```

Comment: Please include your @material-ui/core version and the full error message (includes stack trace)

Comment: @epsilon Updated.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the stack trace. Are you actually wrapping your component in MuiThemeProvider in your tests? Most people don't do this because they rely on shallow rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't use a theme that's similar to the one mentioned in the migration guide:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
  },
});
```

or set `window.__MUI_USE_NEXT_TYPOGRAPHY_VARIANTS__ = true;` if you don't use the theme.

Comment: I use custom theme as mentioned in the guide.

Comment: const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
    fontFamily: '"Lato", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
    htmlFontSize: 16
  },

  shape: {
    borderRadius: 0
  },

  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: "#A6CAE8",
      main: "#7bacd5",
      dark: "#3975A7",
      contrastText: "#fff"
    },
    secondary: {
      light: "#AEB5DE",
      main: "#ff00a8",
      dark: "#585F8B",
      contrastText: "#CACCDE"
    }
  }
});

Comment: I have some custom changes as well in theme.

Comment: Are you sure that a `MuiThemeProvider` with that theme is at the top of your component tree? Any material-ui component not wrapped in that provided could trigger that warning.

Comment: I have defined the custom theme in App.js, and added in the following way:

<MuiThemeProvider theme={slickTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">
          {isLoading ? <Loader /> : null}
          {isAutheticated ? (
            <Layout>{routes}</Layout>
          ) : (
            <Fragment>{routes}</Fragment>
          )}
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>

Comment: This <App/> is wrapped by react router dom in Index.js